# Adding INDEX to IFeatureClass with ArcGIS SDK for Java?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, arcgis-9.3, java, feature-class

I want to add an index to a feature class. To do so, I used the very short and complete example given there:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/b22267cb-642c-11dc-9ca3-0b35f906bb2e.htm

My modified code is below. When I use that code, I obtain an exception due to a **Cast** problem; It cannot cast from a **IFeatureClass** to a **ISchemaLock**:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFeatureClassProxy cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.ISchemaLock*

Are you able to run this code sucessfully without the error ?

If you want to run this code, you have to change the 2 first string inputs in the code (the path and name of your shapefile)

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.AoInitialize;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.esriLicenseProductCode;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.esriLicenseStatus;
import com.esri.arcgis.datasourcesfile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.Fields;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFeatureClass;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IField;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFields;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFieldsEdit;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IIndex;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IIndexEdit;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.ISchemaLock;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IWorkspace;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.Index;
import com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.esriSchemaLock;


public class classmain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try
        {
        // >>> Enter here the path and the name of your shapefile.
        String folderPath = "D:\\ShapeFolder\\test";
        String shapefileName = "myShape_022";

        // Step 1: Initialize the Java Component Object Model (COM) Interop.
        EngineInitializer.initializeEngine();

        // Step 2: Initialize an ArcGIS license.
        AoInitialize aoInit = new AoInitialize();
        aoInit.initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);

        // Load the  ShapeFile into "featureClass"
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.openFromFile(folderPath, 0);
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
        IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass(shapefileName);

        // Find the field "FID" in featureClass that will be used as an index
        int fieldIndex = featureClass.findField("FID");

        // Get the specified field from the feature class.
        IFields featureClassFields = featureClass.getFields();
        IField field = featureClassFields.getField(fieldIndex);

        // Create a new fields collection and add the specified field to it.
        IFields fields = new Fields();
        IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)fields;
        fieldsEdit.setFieldCount(1);
        fieldsEdit.setFieldByRef(0, field);

        //Create a new index and cast to the IIndexEdit interface.
        IIndex index = new Index();
        IIndexEdit indexEdit = (IIndexEdit)index;

        // Set the index's properties, including the fields it will have associated with it.
        indexEdit.setFieldsByRef(fields);
        indexEdit.setIsAscending(false);
        indexEdit.setIsUnique(false);
        indexEdit.setName("IndexFID");

        //Attempt to acquire an exclusive schema lock on the feature class.
        ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)featureClass;
        schemaLock.changeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
        featureClass.addIndex(index);
        schemaLock.changeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);

        //  Disconnect licences 
        aoInit.shutdown();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("App failed.");
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: try to give specific method. people don't like to see huge code segment.

Answer (score 2):

Ihad the same problem and I resolved it by casting featureClass from IFeatureClass  to FeatureClass:

```
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass(shapefileName);
FeatureClass featureClass2= new FeatureClass(featureClass);
.....
//Attempt to acquire an exclusive schema lock on the feature class.
  ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)featureClass2;
.....
```